# Syntax error on vm.js when running react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I created a basic react-app with "npm install -g create-react-app" and then "create-react-app my-app".

After entering "npm start" into my command line, the localhost view is still available, but runninmg the app.js in Visual Studio Code leads to that error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=37970 src\App.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:37970/b058e445-c99e-4b27-bb5d-
```

3477c4edc040
    For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
    Debugger attached.
    c:\Users......\src\App.js:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, 
    { Component } from 'react';
                                                                     ^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
```

So, my new app is just a default app, which leads me to believe that something is not adjusted the right way on my computer system.

Before I tried to run a default app, I created another app with a little content, which was running first, but then after submitting it to git and github and restarting the computer it didn't work anymore, with exactly the same error message. That app, after entering "npm start", wouldn't even cause the localhost to start.

Does anyone of you have an idea what could cause this problem?

I appreciate any hint.

Thank you!

Comment: how did you fix this?

Comment: Not at all. But, as it turned out, it has to do with with my git repository. Somehow a filename was changed by git which seems to cause the error when I'm running the code, the file package.json.
But I don't know how to fix it.